# Audiocallback in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, audio, callback

I'm implementing an audiosynthesizer. I have a AudioCallback Function, which is called (by the Soundcarddriver !?), when Audiodata is needed. Now i want to create a GUI in Qt.But this does not work, because the Callbackfunction disturbs the GUI (I think this is the problem).

My Question:

1) How can I implement the Callbackfunction in Qt ?
2) Is it reasonable to use different threads for audio and gui ?
   or is there, for the beginning, an easier solution ?

Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you intend processing audio with low latency - which is an absolute requirement for any softsynth used in real-time - using a separate thread for audio rendering is mandatory, furthermore, you want it have real-time scheduling priority.  You certainly don't want to give this to your UI code.

Audio needs frequent servicing - possibly as often as once a millisecond.  The UI thread is busy with other duties, and whilst dispatching UI events it can't process audio.   The latency achievable by the system is constrained by the longest scheduling latency for filling a audio buffer. This will be potentially unbounded on the UI thread.

It's not clear to me which library you are using to gain access to audio IO - or indeed on which platform. `QAudioOutput` provided by QtMultimedia doesn't seem to be quite what you want here.

Most likely that the audio render callback happens with very little interaction with Qt.  You certainly don't want to post render requests onto the UI thread - which might seem like a natural paradigm for QT development.

Depending on how your platform's audio library is set up:

1. You create a real-time thread and block until for the buffer to need filling (Linux/Alsa); or,
2. The audio library does this for you and calls you back (MacOSX & iOS/CoreAudio)

In your render thread, do should do nothing besides generating the data to fill the output buffer, and you perform no operations that could block.

The slightly hairy bit is thread-safety getting note data into the render loop. To avoid priority inversion when accessing the event queue, this normally implemented as a lockless FIFO.    If you intend to trigger UI updates from within the render thread, you need to post these onto the UI loop.  Qt's signals and slots are a good choice for this.

If the real aim of your project is to develop a soft-synth, you might be better off developing a [VST](http://www.steinberg.net/en/products/vst.html) plug-in.  There are plenty of open source VST hosts that take care of the threading issues.

You might also consider having a look at [Juce](http://rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce.php) - which provides source code for VST hosts and plug-ins.